# Calculate intersect area for every feature in layer (ArcGIS Pro)

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, area, overlay, watershed

I have a .shp with multiple watersheds. I have a .shp with all the wetlands in the watersheds. I want to know for each watershed the area occupied by wetlands. So for watershed #1 there's Xkm2 of wetlands, for watershed #2 there is Xkm2 etc..

I tried using overlay, but it only gives me the total for all the watersheds.

What tool should I use or do I need Python for this or ModelBuilder?

Answer (score 1):

[image]

You can use the [Intersect](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/analysis/intersect.htm) geoprocessing tool to create an area value for each overlapping polygon.

[image]

Then [Dissolve](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/data-management/dissolve.htm) the result on the watershed field, and include the option to get the sum of area for the wetland overlays.

[image]

From here, you can use [Join Fields](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/data-management/join-field.htm) to add the wetland total areas in watersheds, to the watersheds feature class.

[image]

I just renamed the SUM_Shape_Area to Wetlands_Area, and here it is:
[image]